# The resulted approximation of using user defined constraints on SVMs

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, duality-theorems, constraint-programming

I need your help in getting an insightful information regarding the following problem:

Let $P \subset \mathbb{R}^d, Y \subset \left\lbrace 1,-1\right\rbrace$ a subset of points of cardinality $n$ and corresponding labels of cardinality $n$.

Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha_1 > 0$, such that:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{w \in \mathbb{R}^d, b \in \mathbb{R}, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_{\textit{SVM}}(P,w,b, \eta) = \frac{\left\| w\right\|_2^2}{2} + C \left\| \xi \right\|_1 \\
& \text{subject to} 
& & y_i(p_i^Tw + b) \geq 1 - \xi_i, \; i = 1, \ldots, n \\
&&& \left\| \xi_i \right\|_\infty \geq 0 \\
&&& \left\| w\right\|_2 \leq \alpha_1 \\\
&&& b \leq \alpha_2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$
where $\forall_{i \in [n]} \xi_i$ is the $i^{\textit{th}}$ element of $\xi$.

Based on this, the duality conditions would change, resulting in different SVM solver which is usually weaker (higher error) however if the $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are actual upper bound to the optimal solution (as without these defined user constraints) then we would yield the same value as if we did not impose these constraints.

With that being said, is their a way to bound the approximation from above or at least approximate it w.r.t. the optimal value $\textit{OPT}$, i.e let $\phi \geq 1$, and let $\hat{w} \in \mathbb{R}^d, \hat{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}$ be the solutions of the defined optimization problem such that
$$ 
\phi = \frac{f_{\textit{SVM}}(P,\hat{w},\hat{\beta})}{\textit{OPT}}
$$

To clarify: we want to compare the optimal objective value of the traditional SVM problem with a variant that includes an additional constraint on the norm of $w$ and the value of bias $b$. We are interested in the optimality gap between the two problem variants. By inspection, it's clear that the SVM formulation with the additional constraints will be inferior to the one without the constraints, but we would like to quantify and bound the gap.

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: SVMs doest not apply user defined constraints such as the ones that are defined upon the norm of the weight vector and over $\beta$.
What we are seeking, is to quantify the approximation yielded by such actions, i.e. applying such constraints.

Comment: You want to know how much replacing $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ by $(\infty,\infty)$ will change the optimal value of the objective function at most, that's it ?

Comment: not really, fix $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ then how much would it affect the value of the function as in terms of the optimal value (if we did not impose the such constraints)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To clarify: we want to compare the optimal objective value of the traditional SVM problem with a variant that includes an additional constraint on the norm of $w$ and the value of bias $b$. We are interested in the optimality gap between the two problem variants. By inspection, it's clear that the SVM formulation with the additional constraints will be inferior to the one without the constraints, but we would like to quantify and bound the gap.

Comment: Come on. From your minimization problem there is the optimal value of the objective $f_{P,\alpha_1,\alpha_2}(\hat{w},\hat{b},\hat{\xi})$ and you want to compare it with $f_{P,\infty,\infty}(\hat{w},\hat{b},\hat{\xi})$ the optimal value of the objective when removing the constraints $\le \alpha_i$.